# Does Apache NetBeans 12.1 support JDK 15?

Tags: java, netbeans, java-15

Oracle recently released JDK 15, and I'm wondering if Apache NetBeans 12.1, the latest version of the NetBeans IDE, supports JDK 15. I understand that NetBeans doesn't officially support JDK 15, but I'm asking if anyone knows that it unofficially supports it. Thanks!

Comment: In the old days they would. Not now. 

Best bet is the IntelliJ community edition which brings the Java to run on so java 15 only applies to your own code.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen OK, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apache NetBeans 12 feature update 1 (NB 12.1) was released on September 1, 2020; JDK 15 was released on September 15, 2020. JDK 15 was released after NetBeans 12.1 so it is not officially supported.
Also as mentioned by the [NetBeans download page](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb121/nb121.html), JDK 14 was the latest JDK version at the time when NetBeans 12.1 was released.

**However** I downloaded NB 12.1 and JDK 15 and tried it. **It seems to have no problems**. I also created a simple hello world example using JDK 15's text block and it works as expected (code below).

```java
public class NewClass {
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
     String txtblock = """
     hello world
                      """;
     System.out.println(txtblock);
    }
}
```

[image: About screen of NB 12.1 running JDK 15]